# HTML Canvas; Given two Xs and two Ys, Center Text within

Tags: html, canvas

I am making a series of rectangles. This is not the entire script, this code will actually be *within* a function with parameters for x and y coordinates and parameters for height and width.  This function will be used to create **multiple rectangles**.  My question is that I need to **center the text within rectangles** of x,y,width and height ... and the text will **vary in length**.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="350">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var x = 10;
    var y = 10;
    var width = 180;
    var height = 75;

    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ctx = c.getContext("2d"); 


    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.strokeStyle="black";    
    ctx.strokeRect(x,y,width,height);       

    ctx.textBaseline = 'top';  
    ctx.font         = '20px Sans-Serif';
    ctx.fillStyle    = 'blue';
    ctx.fillText  ("hello", 30, 50);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you just asking for an equation to center one rectangle within another rectangle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `measureText` method of your context to calculate the position of your text before drawing it.

Comment: centerX -(Math.round(ctx.measureText(text).width/2))  This worked for the width, but for some convoluted reason, I need to do the height by hand as the font size changes. Still a big improvement; thanks.

Answer (score 2):

to center vertically use this:

```
context.textBaseline = "middle";

y_pos = text_area_height / 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the textAlign property:

context.textAlign = 'center';

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-text-align/